# virtualenv pip does not upgrade

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

My system pip is install in /opt/.../site-packages. It is versio 1.5.6. In a new virtualenv I run `pip install -U pip`. I see:

```
...Downloading pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB): 1.3MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 1.5.6
Not uninstalling pip at /opt/site-packages, outside environment /home/venv
Successfully installed pip
Cleaning up...
 Removing temporary dir /home/venv/build...
```

But `pip -V` now still says `pip 1.5.6 from /opt/.../site-packages`

Both `pip` and `pip2` present in the `venv/bin` dir show the same. `which pip` points to the `pip` in the `venv/bin` path, so it looks like that pip bin is just never being updated. How do I use the new pip I just installed in my virtual environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was `(virtualenv):easy_install -U pip`

Answer (score 0):

Seems that virtualenv is preventing you to access any module outside the virtual environment home. If you want to upgrade your system `pip`, do it from outside the virtual environment. Anyway when upgrading `pip` it's better not to call the binary itself. Try this in your virtualenv:

```
 python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: I can't upgrade my system pip. I wanted to have a new version installed in my virtualenv and use that when the venv is activated.

Comment: Running the command inside your virtualenv should do the trick

Comment: No dice. `pip -V` still gives `pip 1.5.6` from my system dir

Comment: Do you want to use the pip version in your virtualenv from **outside** your virtualenv???

Comment: No. I want to use it in the virtualenv. I'm in the virtualenv running the upgrade and -V commands.

Comment: Can you please check that `which pip` returns the path to the pip executable **inside** your virtualenv (which doesn't seem to be the case).

Comment: `which pip` returns the path inside the `venv/bin` but that `pip` binary in that path isn't the right one. It's the old version copied in the initial setup of the venv. If I `cd` to that path and run that bin explicitly its the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you create your virtual environment, it will use the packages bundled with that version. If you install a new version of virtualenv you will need to re-create the environment to make use of the new package bundle.

Other alternatives are to manually upgrade the packages within the virtual environment.